# How to draw grid on window using graphics library in python

Tags: python

I want to draw grid onto the window so that I can easily draw rectangles and know the exact points. I have not been able to figure out a way in python using graphics library. Is there a better method?

I could not find anything online that uses graphics mostly.

This is what I have so far:

```
from graphics import *

def main():
    win = GraphWin('Floor', 500, 500)
    win.setCoords(0.0, 0.0, 10.0, 10.0)
    win.setBackground("yellow")

    square = Rectangle(Point(5,5), Point(6,6))
    square.draw(win)
    square.setFill("black")

    win.getMouse()
    win.close()

main()
```

Comment: it seems that the graphics library do not provide any module to draw grid. as in [HERE](http://mcsp.wartburg.edu/zelle/python/graphics/graphics.pdf). One method is to draw lines using two loops (one nested inside another) and changing the x and y coordinates accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easy way would be to add a grid just by calculating some pixels yourself:

```
from graphics import *

def main():
    win = GraphWin('Floor', 500, 500)

    win.setCoords(0.0, 0.0, 10.0, 10.0)
    win.setBackground("yellow")

    # draw grid
    for x in range(10):
        for y in range(10):
            win.plotPixel(x*50, y*50, "blue")

    square = Rectangle(Point(5,5), Point(6,6))
    square.draw(win)
    square.setFill("black")

    win.getMouse()
    win.close()

main()
```

Which adds a 10x10 pixel grid to your yellow window:

[image: Image with grid]

You could do the same by drawing whole lines (as described in the [docs](http://mcsp.wartburg.edu/zelle/python/graphics/graphics/node5.html)) if necessary, at cost of drawing speed (depending on how big your grid size should be).